# Как превратить curl запрос в GET

Tags: c#, curl, get

Gismeteo API выдает погоду по такому запросу

```
curl -H 'X-Gismeteo-Token: 56b30cb255.3443075'  
'https://api.gismeteo.net/v2/weather/current/4368/?lang=en'
```

Можно ли сделать из этого обычную строку для GET запроса?
Пробовал
`https://api.gismeteo.net/v2/weather/current/4368/?lang=en&X-Gismeteo-Token=56b30cb255.3443075`

Говорит
`Invalid token. Check the 'X-Gismeteo-Token' header`

Comment: `-H` - заголовок, а вы передаете в строке запроса как параметр...

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо по урлу запроса
https://api.gismeteo.net/v2/weather/current/4368/?lang=en

передать хэдер с токеном, где имя хэдера "X-Gismeteo-Token", а его значение "56b30cb255.3443075"

Comment: Что такое `request`?

Comment: Это запрос, который вы формируете на сервере. Каким образом вы сейчас отправляете get запрос?

Comment: Я не автор вопроса, я ничего не отправляю. `request` - это переменная, какого она типа? Где она объявлена? Из какой библиотеки этот класс? Я таких в составе дотнета не знаю.

Comment: поправила ответ )

Answer (score 0):

Так должно все работать только TOKEN необходимо получить персональный

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
    webClient.Headers.Add("X-Gismeteo-Token", "56b30cb255.3443075");
    str = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.gismeteo.net/v2/weather/current/4368/?lang=en");
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
    }
```